# Why does numpy.memmap.flush() not update file in Windows?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-memmap

I am currently copying/reformatting data from disk into a memmapped-numpy array.
I call flush() every ~5000 elements, but the change-date in Windows does not change.

```
dimx = 400000
dimy = 100
dimz = 16
data_in: np.memmap = np.memmap(fname_input, dtype='float32', mode='r+', shape=(dimx, dimy, dimz))
for i in range(dimx):
    data = next(data_generator)
    data_in[i] = data

    if (i % 5000) is 0 and i is not 0:
        data_in.flush()
        print('changes flushed to disk.')
```

Comment: Apparently this is a Windows-thing.

Comment: The file is actually updated but Windows does not reflect that